# When did chairs with arms and backs develop in Europe?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, everyday-life, furniture

There are numerous depictions of early / high medieval Popes, Kings and Bishops sat on thrones, with arms and a back, and the saddles of the high medieval period had a padded back, but every depiction I've come across of a seated mortal, before the 15th Century, is shown sat on a stool or bench.

I'm curious when chairs emerged in Europe, if there were any rules prohibiting comfy chairs from all but the highest, or whether the depiction rules are purely an artistic thing / convention?

Comment: Have you seen [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chair#History) of the wiki article?

Comment: a simple stool is cheaper, takes less skill and materials to build. They're also smaller. Of course Joe Average who had to make his own furniture would build those rather than ornate thrones for his tiny hovel.

Comment: Have you sat on a bench,  chest, stool for a few hours. Not very comfy, and as chairs were known, I can't see what was stopping carpenters, who were constructing houses, tables, chests, .... For the masses, to stick a back and some arms on a stool. There are some posh examples eg. http://royalfurniture.org/pic_023.html

Comment: "A  simple stool" is what Roman consul sat on. I can't say when exactly European rulers started using armchairs but they used "stools" for such a long time due to the tradition not comfort.

Comment: Umm, *peasant life in the Middle Ages was not "comfy" in general*. Of course carpenters *can* build fully fledged chairs, but benches have significantly lower material cost and were the most common furniture for that reason.

Comment: @Semaphore Barron's and assorted other nobility had a fairly comfy time, but they are also depicted as sat on benches / stools, rather than chairs / thrones. So as chairs existed, and if the case of the nobility / middle class there was not an economic constraint, why aren't there more chairs / depictions of people sat on them ?

Comment: @user4419802 - the simple stool Roman officials used is a modified camp stool.  So it is reflecting the consuls role as a supreme military leader.

Comment: @Oldcat Nope. Even the part of aediles had the right to use the curule seat. And aedile is the civil rank. The point is that Romans borrowed the curule seat from Etruscans. So it's probable that Etruscans considered this seat as a kind of 'camp stool', but not Romans.

Answer (score 4):

Chairs have always been in use. There are chairs in Tutankhamen's tomb. The Romans used high-backed chairs extensively especially by women, which were called a "cathedra." Our word "cathedral" comes from this word, a cathedral being the "seat" of a bishop. Such chairs were also in use among the Greeks.

[image]

Ancient Roman chair.

[image]